# Selenium. Как выбрать рандомный элемент в select

Tags: python, selenium

Как выбрать рандомный элемент в select в питоне с помощью Selenium.
Или как получить все элементы ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После того, как вы сделали:

```
browser.get('example.com')
```

делаете:

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*')
random_element = elements[random.randint(0, len(elements)-1)]
```

Здесь в коде:

`'//*'` - буквально значит - "Все элементы"

`len(elements)-1` - вернёт число равное, количеству найденных элементов (это все элементы из xPath адреса выше) минус один, так как индексация начинается с 0, а не с 1.

`random.randint(0, len(elements)-1)` - вернёт случайное Целое число из последовательности от 0 до "количества найденных элементов минус 1"

`elements[random.randint(0, len(elements)-1)]` - обращение к элементу в списке по случайному индексу